# A tool that automatically lays blocks and walls?

Tags: terraria

I have seen an item in-game several times but thought nothing of it. The item was meant to automatically lay block. Another was used to lay background. I cannot seem to find them now that I want to see what they do.

What do they do, and how do I obtain them. Does anyone know what they were named?

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear? I have never heard of an item that automatically places things down for you. I know of some things like the wands that can place dirt blocks down or the new leaf/tree wands that change normal into living versions respectively. I just have not seen a general one.

Comment: I don't remember the exact name or description. It was a machine looking thing. I did not read it clearly but it said something about laying block or background automatically. Maybe I mis-read it.

Comment: Looking on the Wiki there just is not an item that seems to do generic blocks and walls that I can see. Sorry.

Comment: There is the cement mixer and brick layer that were added to the game in the most recent patch. Not sure if those are what you're looking for but they can be bought randomly from the traveling merchant.

Comment: That was it. Portable cement mixer. I found that. Where do I get the brick layer? If one of you want to put this into an answer, I will accept it right away. That was what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Traveling Merchant](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Traveling_Merchant) sells the items you are looking for, though none of them automatically take any action (excepting the Paint Sprayer). Instead, each item increases the speed at which your character lays blocks / walls. They each cost 10 gold and are sold randomly (the merchant may not have them in stock each time he visits).

- [Brick Layer](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Brick_Layer) - increases the player's placement speed when placing blocks, furniture, and any other placeable items
- [Portable Cement Mixer](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Portable_Cement_Mixer) - increases the speed a player can place background walls
- [Extendo Grip](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Extendo_Grip) - extends your block mining and placement reach by 3 tiles
- [Paint Sprayer](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Paint_Sprayer) - automatically applies paints to objects when placing them (requires that paint be in the player's inventory in order to function)

Comment: I came across this "feature" recently and then disappeared (maybe I unequipped an item?).
It automatically placed walls: with just holding click in one position, it filled with walls block by block (which was highlighted) my background. Sounds bizarre but was so convenient and happened joining single player after leaving a multiplayer server.

Comment: @George I think you're talking about the _smart cursor_ feature, which you can enable by clicking the left Ctrl key.

Comment: Adding on to Jonah Bishop, if you want the effects of all four, you have to combine them all at a Tynkers Workshop, but this only works for PC, Mobile, and New Gen Consoles. So ya... but you have to put them all in four different slots for 3DS and Old Gen Consoles if you don't have one of the three newer consoles listed above.